# check if an element of a list of char is in string

Tags: java

I'm trying to do some code that for a given string and a given list of chars ( unicode chars , unicode for different kind of dash eg: {\u2011 , \u00AD , \u2013 }), It can check if any char of my list of chars is present at the end of that string ( might be present twice ) and delete it until i have no space or an element of my list as the end char of the string.

I don't know how to initialize a list of chars ( using unicode )  in java and couldn't find an answer on the net.
I though of reversing the string and check for every char from there.
I already tried with **regex** but it's too slow.

```
Input : 
foo oof ofo-
Output : 
foo oof ofo-
```

```
Input : 
foo oof ofo --
Output : 
foo oof ofo
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a loop, updating a variable to keep track of how much you are deleting.

```
Set<Character> charactersIWantToDelete = new HashSet<Character>(
    Arrays.asList('\u2011', '\u00AD', '\u2013', ' ')
    // whatever characters you want to delete
);
int newLen = string.length();
while (newLen > 0 && charactersIWantToDelete.contains(string.charAt(newLen-1)) {
    --newLen;
}
string = string.substring(0, newLen);
```